# Haskell equivalent to C++ template over non-types

Tags: c++, templates, haskell, types

My general understanding is that Haskell typeclasses share some conceptual similarities with C++ templates - namely that you can define functions or types parametrized over types. However, a useful feature of C++ templates is that you can also have non-type template arguments. For example, Wikipedia has a [great example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)#Generic_programming_features_in_other_languages) of how you can create a compile time factorial.

I would ideally like to do the same sort of thing in Haskell... and I almost can with the `DataKinds` extension. Take the classic example of a vector that encodes its length in its type (taken from [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/promotion.html)).

```
data Nat = Ze | Su Nat

data Vec :: * -> Nat -> * where
  Nil  :: Vec a Ze
  Cons :: a -> Vec a n -> Vec a (Su n)
```

I would like to be able to 'demote' the type-level 'Nat' of a vector back down to the value level (maybe  with `ScopedTypeVariables`) so I can use it, as one can use C++ non-type template arguments as constant values. [GHC.TypeLits](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html) sort of does this with some hackery in the `KnownNat` class (it fakes instances for every concrete literal), but I obviously can't write this myself in Haskell.

I get the feeling that what I want is not possible but I would like to have some intuition about why it might not be possible.

I feel that dependent types are lurking about...

Comment: You can do it yourself, but inefficiently. `data Nat = Z | S Nat`. `class Natty (n :: Nat) where natty :: proxy n -> Nat` and one instance for `'Z` and another for `'S n`.

Comment: Everyone suggesting that OP use singletons when `Vec ()` is the singleton for `Nat`.... meaning that you don't need to write a singleton, because induction on your `Vec` types gives you all the power of a singleton for Nat.  You can also get the value level representation of the type level length of a vector with the simple function `len : Vec x n -> Integer; len Nil = 0; len (Cons _ xs) = 1 + len xs`.

Comment: Don't forget we have type families, which can combined with `UndecidableInstances`. E.g. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-level-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique to do this is called [singleton types](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) (that link also links to a library to support this).

The core idea is you make a parameterized type constructor so that there's a one-to-one correspondence between the values of the type and the type parameters.  Here's a simplified example taken from the first paper referenced in the link above.

```
data SBool (a :: Bool) where
    STrue :: SBool 'True
    SFalse :: SBool 'False
```

Now there is only one value of type `SBool 'True` namely `STrue`.  We also, via GADT magic, know that when we pattern match on a `SBool a` and get `STrue` then `a ~ 'True`.  Now, to go back to values we use the normal mechanism for choosing a value based on type: type classes.

```
class FromSBool (a :: 'Bool) where
    fromSBool :: SBool a -> Bool

instance FromSBool 'True where
    fromSBool STrue = True

instance FromSBool 'False where
    fromSBool SFalse = False
```

This was a very simple example, but the library references papers that go in to more details, or you can just use the library.  You are correct that the type level naturals are somewhat magical.  A related library is the [reflection](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) package which lets you shove a value into a type and get it back later.

If you are interested in some of the theory, you may also be interested in the paper [Hasochism](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! That looks very cool indeed. Unless someone has a better solution, I will accept you answer shortly.